# Merge k sorted arrays - comparing two solutions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

If I have K sorted arrays of N elements each, e.g.

```
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 6, 8]
[10, 11, 12]
```

I know that I can use a heap to merge them by cycling all of the lists and their elements and inserting them into the heap, then getting back the minimum each time in O(KN * log(KN)).

I checked on the internet and another popular solution seems to be using a min heap of only K elements and inserting all the first items of the K lists into the heap, then get the minimum out and advance the pointer to the list that owned that minimum element.

Aside from a more efficient memory requirement (O(K) in the second case), is the second method more efficient time-wise?

Optional bonus points: is there an even better algorithm than the ones above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version should have a runtime of O(KN* log(K)) since you perform a heapify (log (K)) operation for each element (N*K). So yes it is faster. I cannot think of a more efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is fine when you have enough memory to perform the sorting of all the input lists, but it'd be even simpler to just perform a k-way merge between the already-sorted lists, with a bit of extra space (a list of K elements) for keeping track of the index where you're at each input list. That's an `O(K^2 * N)` solution.

Which is better - the first method or the k-way merge, depends on how big is K compared to N, and let's not forget the `O(KN)` cost of building a heap for the first method. To give an idea:

```
k=5; n=100
k*n*log(k*n)
=> 3107
k*k*n
=> 2500

k=100; n=100
k*n*log(k*n)
=> 92103
k*k*n
=> 1000000
```

The second method uses less memory, and that's very important! it's the way to go when the input lists don't fit in memory - hence we'd take one element from each list, put it in the heap, determine the next one that goes into the final result, and write it to the output, updating the heap accordingly: that's `O(KN * log(K))` in complexity. Again, to give an idea:

```
k=5; n=100
k*n*log(k)
=> 804

k=100; n=100
k*n*log(k)
=> 46051
```

Bottom line: Use a k-way merge instead of the first method when the input fits in memory and k is small, and as @btilly points out, the second method is theoretically the best of them all, but practical considerations might make a k-way merge faster. As usual: the best strategy is to profile with some real data, and pick the winner!

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Wouldn't a k-way merge be slower? Since you will have to always make K comparisons at each step (as opposed to fewer comparisons with a heap tree which is partially sorted)

Comment: Can you please explain O(KN) solution?
Maybe I don't understand your point, but choosing next element will take O(K) time, so it will be O(K^2*N) solution.

Comment: @alper You're right, I had not taken into account the cost of choosing the next element :/ I'll update my answer. But anyway, if we used a heap we must also pay the O(KN) cost of building it. In the end, the best alternative depends on the size of K

Comment: @ÓscarLópez so far your solution does not consider the problem of finding the minimum of the K lowest elements, which would add an extra factor of K in the naive case. Dean already mentioned that this can be done by a heap in this second proposed method.

Comment: Your O(K^N) solution is actually O(KN * K), or O(NK^2). Basically, for every item you do K comparisons. You have N*K items. So, N*K*K, or N*K^2.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Choosing top element from heap will cost `O(log(heap-size))` (= `O(logK)`).

Comment: Yes, it's O(K^2 * N), the `2` was missing there

Comment: @alper O(log(KN)) for the first method

Comment: The second method is theoretically strictly preferable to both the first method and the k-way merge.  The k-way merge may be practically better when comparisons are cheap and pipeline stalls in the CPU are an issue because you get to use compare-and-swap operations and so branch prediction becomes perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is `O(KN * log(KN))`  The second is `O(KN * log(K))` and so is better.  It is impossible to in general do better than that.

That said, you can improve on it sometimes in practice.  Instead of dumping the minimum elements into a heap, create a tree of merges like merge-sort does.  Then add logic to, when you seem to be pulling from one side of the merge, try to jump ahead and look for a run.

The win can be significant if `K` is large, comparisons are expensive, and your data has lots of runs.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort for an example of a sorting algorithm which tries something like this, and has been finely tuned for a lot of real world use cases.